# window.URL || window.webkitURL not working with Safari browser version prior 5

Tags: javascript

The `window.URL` and `window.webkitURL` are not working with *Safari* browser version prior 5

```
        function onFileSelected(event) {
            var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        }
```

can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `window.URL` APIs are not supported on Safari 5. Take a look at the table here: http://caniuse.com/#search=createObjectURL

Only the most recent versions of current browsers support the API.